# Why my train_test_split doesn't work with stratify option?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am running below code to split data evenly but the data is not split as expected.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(label, test_size = 0.5, stratify= label, random_state=1)
```

It returns: 

 y_train.shape = (115956,)

 y_test.shape = (22,)

feature shape: (123670, 15), 

label shape: (123670,), 

label.value_counts() return: 

 0    123578

 1        92

If I **remove stratify** option, it works fine. Does anybody know why? I am so confused.

Scikit-learn==0.23.1

I really need help and this issue has been killing me :(

Comment: Could give a bit more context? How does `label` look like? How do you get the shapes?

Comment: why do u want to split only the labels rather both X and labels?

Comment: Are you sure that they are classification labels and not regression labels. Can you show a sample of a `label` variable?

Comment: of course, label only contains 0 and 1